# Arduino SPI.transfer to WiringPi wiringPiSPIDataRW

Tags: c++, c, raspberry-pi

I'm new with C/C++

On Arduino I have this kind of command to send a byte over SPI bus (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPITransfer):

```
ReceiveByte(char UART) {
 SPI.transfer(0x20 | UART);
 ...
 return SPI.transfer(0xFF);
}
```

now I would like to make this wiht WiringPi library and have this functions to write to SPI:

```
int wiringPiSPIDataRW (int channel, unsigned char *data, int len) ;
```

Can someone help me how to send: 0x20 | UART with wiringPiSPIDataRW function?

thank you

Comment: What is wiringPiSPI library?

Comment: wiringPiSPI library is C library to access GPIO bus on OrangePI PC or RaspberryPi PC.. https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/blob/master/wiringPi/wiringPiSPI.c

Comment: `char value = 0x20 | UART; wiringPiSPIDataRW(???, &value, 1);` ?